# Assembly Line in Golang using concurrency

Tags: concurrency, go

New to Go. I'm attempting to code an "assembly line" where multiple functions act like workers and pass some data structure to each other down the line, each doing something to the data structure.

```
type orderStruct struct {
    orderNum,capacity int
    orderCode uint64
    box [9]int
}


func position0(in chan orderStruct){

    order := <-in

    if((order.orderCode<<63)>>63 == 1){
        order.box[order.capacity] = 1
        order.capacity += 1
    }

    fmt.Println("  filling box {", order.orderNum, order.orderCode, order.box, order.capacity, "} at position 0")
}

func startOrder(in chan orderStruct){

    order := <-in

    fmt.Printf("\nStart an empty box for customer order number %d , request number %d\n", order.orderNum, order.orderCode)
    fmt.Println("  starting box {", order.orderNum, order.orderCode, order.box, order.capacity, "}")

    d := make(chan orderStruct,1)
    go position0(d)
    d <- order
}

func main() {

    var orders [10]orderStruct
    numOrders := len(os.Args)-1
    var x int

    for i := 0; i < numOrders; i++{
        x, _ = strconv.Atoi(os.Args[i+1])
        orders[i].orderCode = uint64(x)
        orders[i].orderNum = i+1
        orders[i].capacity = 0
        for j := 0; j < 9; j++{
            orders[i].box[j] = 0
        }
        c := make(chan orderStruct)
        go startOrder(c)
        c <- orders[i]
    }
}
```

So basically the issue I'm having is that the print statements in startOrder() execute fine, but when I try to pass the struct to position0(), nothing is printed. Am I misunderstanding how channels work?

Comment: I would recommend reading http://blog.golang.org/pipelines - there are more than a couple things in this design to take issue with.

Comment: (Random observation, to the side of the actual question: I once built a pipeline doing a bunch of things in parallel where the only explicitly concurrent part was a few `go io.Copy(w, r)`s. Not everything's a fit for that model, but when you *can* hide concurrency from a large part of your code, that can be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to re-write what you've written to work properly.  You can [run it on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/nm2MZQGMiP)

The main differences are

- only two go routines are started - these act as the two workers on the production line - one taking orders and the other filling boxes
- use of [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to find out when they end
- use of for x := range channel
- use of close(c) to signal end of channel
- you could start multiple copies of each worker and the code would still work fine (repeat the `wg.Add(1); go startOrders(c, wg)` code)

Here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type orderStruct struct {
    orderNum, capacity int
    orderCode          uint64
    box                [9]int
}

func position0s(in chan orderStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for order := range in {
        if (order.orderCode<<63)>>63 == 1 {
            order.box[order.capacity] = 1
            order.capacity += 1
        }
        fmt.Println("  filling box {", order.orderNum, order.orderCode, order.box, order.capacity, "} at position 0")
    }
}

func startOrders(in chan orderStruct, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    d := make(chan orderStruct)
    wg.Add(1)
    go position0s(d, wg)

    for order := range in {
        fmt.Printf("\nStart an empty box for customer order number %d , request number %d\n", order.orderNum, order.orderCode)
        fmt.Println("  starting box {", order.orderNum, order.orderCode, order.box, order.capacity, "}")
        d <- order
    }
    close(d)
}

func main() {
    var orders [10]orderStruct
    numOrders := 4
    var x int = 10
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    c := make(chan orderStruct)
    wg.Add(1)
    go startOrders(c, wg)
    for i := 0; i < numOrders; i++ {
        orders[i].orderCode = uint64(x)
        orders[i].orderNum = i + 1
        orders[i].capacity = 0
        for j := 0; j < 9; j++ {
            orders[i].box[j] = 0
        }
        c <- orders[i]
    }
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of people reading this code, remember that there are *three* goroutines in total, including the two that were started explicitly and the main goroutine itself.

Comment: So if I wanted to add a function that gets passed the struct from positions0s, would I add the wg.Add(1); go position1s code to position0s?

Comment: Also, when I change numOrders to 5, the 5th box is never filled like the first 4 are?

Comment: @Tarzan forgot the `wg.Wait()`! Have updated the answer.  As for `position1s` - yes you could do it like that.  It might be more orderly to start the whole production line in `startOrders` though - create all the channels there and pass them into the workers.

Answer (score 1):

Pipelines are a great place to start when learning to program concurrently in Go. Nick Craig-Wood's answer provides a working solution to this specific challenge.

There is a whole range of other ways to use concurrency in Go. Broadly, there are three categories divided according to what is being treated as concurrent:

- *Functional decomposition* - Creating pipelines of several functions is a good way to get started - and is your question's topic. It's quite easy to think about and quite productive. However, if it progresses to truly parallel hardware, it's quite hard to balance the load well. Everything goes at the speed of the *slowest* pipeline stage.
- *Geometric decomposition* - Dividing the data up into separate regions that can be processed independently (or without too much communication). Grid-based systems are popularly used in certain domains of scientific high-performance computing, such as weather-forecasting.
- *Farming* - Identifying how the work to be done can be chopped into (a large number of) tasks and these tasks can be allocated to 'workers' one by one until all are completed. Often, the number of tasks *far* exceeds the number of workers. This category includes all the so-called 'embarrassingly parallel' problems (embarrassing because if you fail to get your high-performance system to give linear speed-up, you look a bit daft).

I could add a fourth category of hybrids of several of the above.

There is quite a lot of literature about this, including much from the days of Occam programming in the '80s and '90s. Go and Occam both use CSP message passing so the issues are similar. I would single out the helpful book [Practical Parallel Processing: An introduction to problem solving in parallel](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/pub_master.jsp?id=1000126) (Chalmers and Tidmus 1996).